# CRM 2011 - How to Get the Solution ID

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, solution

I'm developing a WPF application using C#. I need to know how can i get the Id (GUID) of the current Solution. I can see that Id on the bottom of the dialog that CRM displays when you want to modify the Filter Criteria of any view.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it. You have to do a query with a conditionexpression : "uniquename", ConditionOperator.equal,-SOLUTION NAME- . It will be return the Guid of the Solution